# RStudio server gives errors about .Internal whilst typing

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio server. When typing code (either in script or console window) one the following errors sometimes appears in console:

> Error in print.default(item$value) : 
>     9 arguments passed to .Internal(print.default) which requires 3
>
> Error in print.default(functionCall[[1]]) : 
>     9 arguments passed to .Internal(print.default) which requires 3
>
> Error in .Internal(print.function(x, useSource, ...)) : 
>     there is no .Internal function 'print.function'

(The numbers in the first two messages are always 9 and 3.)

Sometimes, it gets so bad that a message appears at every character I type. Often, a pop-up error message "R code execution error" pops up together with the console message.

As for a reproducible example, I seem to get it pretty much whatever I type. The following suffices:

```
a <- 3
b <- 4
vec <- c(a, b)
```

I haven't been able to dig up any useful information about these errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to take this to the RStudio support forums. At the very least you should provide the R and RStudio version numbers. Have you tried clearing the workspace and restarting R?

Comment: The reason this is happening is that Rstudio runs R in the background to get autocomplete suggestions, etc. As Roland suggested, bring this to Rstudio support

Comment: I had same problem: for me caused by (bad) configuration file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ which wipe out LD_LIBRARY_PATH. When RStudio starts it's setup his LD_LIBRARY_PATH then run configuration scripts (like bashrc od ld.so.conf).

Answer (score 1):

RStudio has a support article that answers this, at [Startup error in RStudio IDE - "7 arguments passed to .Internal()"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206188768-Startup-error-in-RStudio-IDE-7-arguments-passed-to-Internal-)

The support article explains that this is most likely due to a conflict with multiple different versions of R, possibly caused by `.Rprofile` or `.Renviron`.